# MSSQL LocalDB with Tedious / TDS

Tags: sql-server, localdb, tds, tedious

does anybody know how to configure Tedious (https://github.com/pekim/tedious) to connect against a Microsoft SQL EXPRESS LocalDB? I don't get it to work.

Since Tedious uses the TDS protocol, I guess the question needs to be: does MSSQL LocalDB support TDS?

thanks a lot
Juergen

Comment: Searching for JDBC for LocalDB, I found that LocalDB only supports Named Pipes (and no Ports). However since jTDS supports LocalDB via Named Pipes, it's obviously not a limitation of the TD protocol. If Tedious supports Named Pipes, it should word. But I don't know yet whether it does or not.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no. From reading a bit on the specification, it is a "used to transfer data between a database server and a client". My gut says localdb doesn't use this same protocol. I've opened an issue on GitHub just to verify.

https://github.com/pekim/tedious/issues/348

Answer (score -1):

1. `server = 'localhost'`  (tedious doesn't like windows strings)
2. `INSTANCENAME = 'SQLEXPRESS`' (OR can put port in)
3. SQL Server Browser must be running

```
var config = {  
      server: 'localhost',  

  authentication: {
          type: 'default',
          options: {
              userName: 'itsME',
              password: 'SecreStuff'
          }
      },
      options: {
        
          instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS',
          encrypt: false,
          database: 'pilotChecks'
      }
```